# How to update LayeredNavigation in ajax responce in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Now i am user controller

```
  $navBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation')
                    ->setTemplate('Mymodul_Mypackage::layer/view.phtml')
                    ->toHtml();
```

Now call custom controller but not get response

Comment: Please explain your question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution

/Vender/Modulename/Alnavigation/Controller/Category/View.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vender\Modulename\Controller\Category;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * Catalog session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_catalogSession;

    /**
     * Catalog design
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design
     */
    protected $_catalogDesign;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator
     */
    protected $categoryUrlPathGenerator;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * Catalog Layer Resolver
     *
     * @var Resolver
     */
    private $layerResolver;

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     * @param Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_catalogDesign = $catalogDesign;
        $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator = $categoryUrlPathGenerator;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize requested category object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    protected function _initCategory()
    {

        $categoryId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
        if (!$categoryId) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category')->canShow($category)) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->_catalogSession->setLastVisitedCategoryId($category->getId());
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('current_category', $category);
        try {
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'catalog_controller_category_init_after',
                ['category' => $category, 'controller_action' => $this]
            );
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return false;
        }

        return $category;
    }

    /**
     * Category view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $ajax = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ajax');
        if(!$ajax){

            if ($this->_request->getParam(\Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
                return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
            }
            $category = $this->_initCategory();

            if ($category) {
                $this->layerResolver->create(Resolver::CATALOG_LAYER_CATEGORY);
                $settings = $this->_catalogDesign->getDesignSettings($category);


                // apply custom design
                if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
                    $this->_catalogDesign->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
                }

                $this->_catalogSession->setLastViewedCategoryId($category->getId());

                $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

                // apply custom layout (page) template once the blocks are generated
                if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
                    $page->getConfig()->setPageLayout($settings->getPageLayout());
                }


                if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
                    $type = $category->hasChildren() ? 'layered' : 'layered_without_children';
                } else {
                    $type = $category->hasChildren() ? 'default' : 'default_without_children';
                }

                if (!$category->hasChildren()) {
                    // Two levels removed from parent.  Need to add default page type.
                    $parentType = strtok($type, '_');
                    $page->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $parentType]);
                }
                $page->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $type, 'id' => $category->getId()]);


                // apply custom layout update once layout is loaded
                $layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates();
                if ($layoutUpdates && is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                    foreach ($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                        $page->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                    }
                }

                $page->getConfig()->addBodyClass('page-products')
                    ->addBodyClass('categorypath-' . $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category))
                    ->addBodyClass('category-' . $category->getUrlKey());


                return $page;


            } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('noroute');
            }

        }else{


            if ($this->_request->getParam(\Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
                return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl());
            }
            $category = $this->_initCategory();

            if ($category) {
                $this->layerResolver->create(Resolver::CATALOG_LAYER_CATEGORY);
                $settings = $this->_catalogDesign->getDesignSettings($category);


                // apply custom design
                if ($settings->getCustomDesign()) {
                    $this->_catalogDesign->applyCustomDesign($settings->getCustomDesign());
                }

                $this->_catalogSession->setLastViewedCategoryId($category->getId());

                $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

                // apply custom layout (page) template once the blocks are generated
                if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
                    //$page->getConfig()->setPageLayout($settings->getPageLayout());
                }


                if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
                    $type = $category->hasChildren() ? 'layered' : 'layered_without_children';
                } else {
                    $type = $category->hasChildren() ? 'default' : 'default_without_children';
                }

                if (!$category->hasChildren()) {
                    // Two levels removed from parent.  Need to add default page type.
                    $parentType = strtok($type, '_');
                    $page->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $parentType]);
                }
                $page->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $type, 'id' => $category->getId()]);

                /*---------------------------------*/
                if ($ajax) {

                $resultPage =$this->resultPageFactory->create();                

                 $navblock = $resultPage->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('\Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category')
                    ->setTemplate('Vander_Modulename::layer/customview.phtml')              
                    ->toHtml();

                }   
                /*---------------------------------*/

                // apply custom layout update once layout is loaded

                $layoutUpdates = $settings->getLayoutUpdates();
                if ($layoutUpdates && is_array($layoutUpdates)) {
                    foreach ($layoutUpdates as $layoutUpdate) {
                        $page->addUpdate($layoutUpdate);
                    }
                }



                $page->getConfig()->addBodyClass('page-products')
                    ->addBodyClass('categorypath-' . $this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category))
                    ->addBodyClass('category-' . $category->getUrlKey());



                if ($ajax) {                    



                    $layout = $resultPage ->getLayout();

                    $listBlock = $layout
                        ->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct')
                        ->setTemplate('Vander_Modulename::product/list.phtml'); 

                    $listBlock->setToolbarBlockName('product_list_toolbar');                      
                    $block = $listBlock->toHtml();

                    $responseData = [
                        'errors' => false,
                        'productdata' => $block,
                        'navigation' => $navblock,
                    ];

                    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);  
                    $resultJson->setData($responseData);
                    return $resultJson;                                     
                    exit(); 

                }   


                return $page;


            } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('noroute');
            }


        }   


    }
}
?>
```

---

customview.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php
/**
 * Category layered navigation
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
 */
 //$block=$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation');
?>
<?php //$filterArray = []; ?>
<?php if ($block->canShowBlock()): ?>
    <div class="block filter" id="layered-filter-block" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "collateral": { "openedState": "filter-active", "element": "body" } }}'>
        <?php $filtered = count($block->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()) ?>
        <div class="block-title filter-title" data-count="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filtered; ?>">
            <strong data-role="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shop By') ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content filter-content">
            <?php // echo $block->getChildHtml('state') ?>
            <?php

            $sblock=$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State');
            ?>
            <?php $_filters = $sblock->getActiveFilters() ?>

<?php if (!empty($_filters)): ?>
<div class="filter-current">
    <strong class="block-subtitle filter-current-subtitle"
            role="heading"
            aria-level="2"
            data-count="<?php echo count($_filters); ?>">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Now Shopping by') ?></strong>

    <?php $filterArray = array(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter):



        if(array_key_exists(trim($_filter->getName()),$filterArray)){           
            if(in_array(trim($_filter->getLabel()),$filterArray[trim($_filter->getName())])){continue;}         
        }       
        $filterArray[trim($_filter->getName())][] = trim($_filter->getLabel());

        ?>
            <li class="item">
                <span class="filter-label"><?php echo $sblock->escapeHtml(__($_filter->getName())); ?></span>
                <span class="filter-value"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $sblock->stripTags($_filter->getLabel()) ?></span>
                <?php
                $clearLinkUrl = $_filter->getClearLinkUrl();
                $currentFilterName = $sblock->escapeHtml(__($_filter->getName())) . " " . $sblock->stripTags($_filter->getLabel());
                if ($clearLinkUrl):
                    ?>
                    <a class="action previous" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_filter->getRemoveUrl() ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Previous') ?>">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Previous') ?></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="action remove"
                       title="<?php echo $sblock->escapeHtml($_filter->getFilter()->getClearLinkText()) ?>"
                       href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $clearLinkUrl ?>">
                        <span><?php echo $sblock->escapeHtml($_filter->getFilter()->getClearLinkText()) ?></span>
                    </a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <a class="action remove" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_filter->getRemoveUrl() ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $sblock->escapeHtml(__('Remove')) . " " . $currentFilterName;?>">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Remove This Item') ?></span>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>


</div>
<?php endif; ?>





            <?php if ($block->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
                <div class="block-actions filter-actions">
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    //echo $block->getClearUrl() ;
                    echo $sblock->getClearUrl();

                    ?>" class="action clear filter-clear"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Clear All') ?></span></a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $wrapOptions = false; ?>
            <?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
                <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <?php if (!$wrapOptions): ?>
                        <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
                        <div class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list" data-role="content" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": false}}'>
                    <?php  $wrapOptions = true; endif; ?>
                    <div data-role="collapsible" class="filter-options-item">
                        <div data-role="title" class="filter-options-title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($filter->getName()) ?></div>
                        <div data-role="content" class="filter-options-content">
                        <?php 
                        /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter);
                        //echo $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter);

                        echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.navigation.renderer')->render($filter);


                        ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php if ($wrapOptions): ?>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <script>
                    require([
                        'jquery'
                    ], function ($) {
                        $('#layered-filter-block').addClass('filter-no-options');
                    });
                </script>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```